# filtering a dataframe after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
In [4]:

df
Out[4]:
Symbol       Date      Strike     C/P  Bid  Ask  
0      GS  6/15/2015     200        c    5   72   
1      GS  6/15/2015     200        p    5   72    
2      GS  6/15/2015     210        c   15    0     
3      GS  6/15/2015     210        p   15   54     
4      GS  7/15/2015     200        c   20   50     
5      GS  7/15/2015     200        p   20    0     
6      GS  7/15/2015     210        c    4   90     
7      GS  7/15/2015     210        p    4   90   
8     IBM  6/15/2015     150        c   12   27    
9     IBM  6/15/2015     150        p   12    0    
10    IBM  6/15/2015     160        c    1   58    
11    IBM  6/15/2015     160        p    1    3     
12    IBM  7/15/2015     120        c   13   39     
13    IBM  7/15/2015     120        p   13   39     
14    IBM  7/15/2015     130        c    4   45     
15    IBM  7/15/2015     130        p    4   45
```

and wish to filter out both c and p for a given strike if either of them has a 0 ask value as below:

```
Symbol  Date     Strike Call/Put    Bid    Ask  yminx
  GS    6/15/2015   200     c          5    72  90
  GS    6/15/2015   200     p          5    72  90
  GS    7/15/2015   210     c          4    90  90
  GS    7/15/2015   210     p          4    90  90
  IBM   6/15/2015   160     c          1    58  58
  IBM   6/15/2015   160     p          1    3   58
  IBM   7/15/2015   120     c         13    39  58
  IBM   7/15/2015   120     p         13    39  58
  IBM   7/15/2015   130     c          4    45  58
  IBM   7/15/2015   130     p          4    45  58
```

I can filter by ask being 0 and remove that row by doing the following:

```
df = df[df.Ask != 0]
```

but I can not figure out how to remove the other row that has the same symbol/date/strike combination but a non zero ask.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out some rows, we need the 'filter' function instead of 'apply'.

```
by = df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Date', 'Strike'])

# this is used as filter function, returns a boolean type selector.
# pandas.groupby.filter() function would be smart enough to keep all those 
# entry with True
def equal_to_45(group):
    # return True if either Call or Put has an Ask = 45
    return any(group.Ask.values == 45)

def keep_geq_45(group):
    # return True if both Call or Put have an Ask great or equal to 45
    # that is equivalent to delete all entries with Ask less than 45
    return all(group.Ask.values >= 45)

# this time, use filter function instead of apply
by.filter(equal_to_45)

Out[242]: 
   Symbol        Date  Strike C/P  Bid  Ask
14    IBM  2015-07-15     130   c    4   45
15    IBM  2015-07-15     130   p    4   45

by.filter(keep_geq_45)

Out[243]: 
   Symbol        Date  Strike C/P  Bid  Ask
0      GS  2015-06-15     200   c    5   72
1      GS  2015-06-15     200   p    5   72
6      GS  2015-07-15     210   c    4   90
7      GS  2015-07-15     210   p    4   90
14    IBM  2015-07-15     130   c    4   45
15    IBM  2015-07-15     130   p    4   45
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the added commentary . . .really helps in the understanding of the "why".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was about to post a similar question. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> mask = df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Date', 'Strike'])['Ask'].transform('all') 
>>> df[~mask]
  Symbol       Date  Strike C/P  Bid  Ask
2     GS  6/15/2015     210   c   15    0
3     GS  6/15/2015     210   p   15   54
4     GS  7/15/2015     200   c   20   50
5     GS  7/15/2015     200   p   20    0
8    IBM  6/15/2015     150   c   12   27
9    IBM  6/15/2015     150   p   12    0
```

so to remove these rows do `df[mask]`.

Comment: That worked but I have no idea how ;-(  I looked at the pandas 16.2 docs and still don't understand how this actually accomplished the objective, but, like I said  . . .it worked so thank you very much!!!